# Returning boolean result when searching a linked list for an existing member - java

Tags: java, linked-list, user-input, boolean-expression, abstract-data-type

I'm writing a program for class that enters the user into an infinite loop and accepts three different commands (add x, delete x, exists x) + an integer value. When the user enters "exists x" the program should return a boolean result indicating if the value exists in the list.

The methods for add x and delete x work just fine, but **when searching the list I cannot produce a "true/false" result. I've tried it a few different ways, here is where I am currently at with the exists x method:**

```
public class LinkedNode {
public int x;         // The data value

public LinkedNode next;  // Reference to the next LinkedNode

// Default constructor
LinkedNode() {
    next = null;
}

// Constructor that initializes the data values
LinkedNode(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void display() {
    System.out.print(x + " ");
}

}


public class Set {

public LinkedNode firstLink;

Set(){
    firstLink = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (firstLink == null); //nothing in Set yet
}

public void add(int x) {
    LinkedNode newLink = new LinkedNode(x);

    newLink.next = firstLink;
    firstLink = newLink;
}

public boolean exists(int x) {

   LinkedNode theLink = firstLink;

   while (theLink.x != x) { // keep searching until match
       if (theLink.next == null) // we've hit the end without a match, return false
               return false;
           else
               theLink = theLink.next;
       }
       return true;
}

public LinkedNode delete(int x) {
    LinkedNode currentLink = firstLink;
    LinkedNode previousLink = firstLink;

    while (currentLink.x != x) { // search while no match is found
        if (currentLink.next == null) {
            return null; // not found
    }   else { // moves to next LinkedNode
        previousLink = currentLink;
        currentLink = currentLink.next;
        }
    }
    if (currentLink == firstLink) { // first link matches search
        firstLink = firstLink.next; // delete link
    }
    else { // any other link is a match except firstLink
        previousLink.next = currentLink.next;
    }
    return currentLink;
}

public String toString() {
    String str = "";

    LinkedNode cur = firstLink;
    while (cur!=null) {
        str += cur.x + " ";
        cur = cur.next;
    }
    return str;
}

}
```

Here is my Test/driver:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set dataSet = new Set();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        while (1<2) { // infinite loop on purpose

        String command, value;
        System.out.print("Enter command: ");
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String [] userInput = line.split(" ");
        command = userInput [0];
        value = userInput [1];

        if (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("add") && !command.equalsIgnoreCase("del") && !command.equalsIgnoreCase("exists")){
            System.out.println("Invalid command.");
            System.out.println("Valid commands are: add x, del x & exists x");
            System.out.print("Enter command: ");
        }
        else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
            dataSet.add(Integer.parseInt(value));
            System.out.println(dataSet);
        }
        else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("del")){
            dataSet.delete(Integer.parseInt(value));
            System.out.println(dataSet);
        }
        else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("exists"));{
            dataSet.exists(Integer.parseInt(value));
            System.out.println(dataSet);

        }
    }
```

**I want the program to display "true/false" if the value searched exists in the link, similar to how it displays the current list after add/delete. Any hints as to where I'm going wrong?**

```
Enter command: add 3
3 
Enter command: add 1
1 3 
Enter command: add 20
20 1 3 
Enter command: exists 20
Enter command:
```

Comment: Can we see your entire class?

Comment: edited to include everything I've written for it.

Comment: And your LinkedNode class

Comment: Sorry - thought it was cutting me off, all inclusive now

Comment: **Remove the `;`** in this line: `else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("exists"));{` --- Also, if you *"want the program to display "true/false""*, then perhaps you should **print the return value** from `dataSet.exists()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close, your code actually works fine it's just you have a small typo in there which is throwing it off!

`else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("exists"));{`

This code contains a semicolon at the end, this is unfortunately valid Java and so doesn't throw any compile-time exceptions. Often though you should get a warning saying:

> Blockquote 'if' statement has empty body

Also, because this is executing each loop your results are getting displayed twice, so removing the semicolon should do the trick:

```
else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("exists")) {
    System.out.println(dataSet.exists(Integer.parseInt(value)));
    System.out.println(dataSet);
}
```

In the code sample, I am printing the result of whether the value exists in the LinkedList just for clarity.

**Note:** It might also be worth adding a new line each time you ask the user to Enter command to allow for the different commands to be split:

```
System.out.print("\nEnter command: ");
```

Once again, this is purely cosmetic, just makes your output a lot more readable!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Andreas & M H - below is what produced the intended output:

```
else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("exists")){
    if(dataSet.exists(Integer.parseInt(value)))
    {
      System.out.println("true");
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.println("false");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should print the value you want, this will help you checking if the method works.

```
else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("exists"){
   if(dataSet.exists(Integer.parseInt(value)))
     System.out.println("true");
   else
      System.out.println("false");`enter code here`
```

You should comprobate too if the list (Set) is empty, probably the code is not working cause of that. Also, it would be more correct if you use local variables as privates. Change them and write methods setX(x), getX() for them. About method exist, I think a better code would be this one :

```
public Boolean exists(int x){
    LinkedNode theLink = firstLink;
    Boolean resul = false;
    while(!isEmpty() && theLink.getNext() != null){
         if(link.getX() != x)
            theLink = theLink.getNext(); 
         else
            resul = true;
    }
    return resul;
```

If you dont want to set local linkedNode variables as private, just change getNext and getX by .next and .x
Try to understand the code and next time, try by yourself more time, is the only way to learn.

Answer (score -1):

Your function is probably returning the right bool value. But you are not printing the result. You can use the following type of code.

```
if(dataSet.exists(Integer.parseInt(value))==True)
{
     system.out.println("exists");
}
else
{
     system.out.println("not exists");
}
```

The above code is just a pseudo code.

Comment: `exists()` returns a `boolean`, so `exists(...) == value` will never compile.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, I used this pseudocode and program works just fine. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Value means True or False her.

Comment: If it work for you, please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: How could `value` have meant True or False, when `value` is a `String` passed to the `parseInt()` method? --- Also, `True` is an unknown variable. It is certainly not a keyword. Besides, `if (exists() == true)` is redundant, and should just be `if (exists())`.

Comment: You haven't edited the answer since my last comment,